# Center of a finite group of order pq

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I have no clue if it is true or false: the center of a group of order pq, where p & q are distinct primes is either the trivial subgroup or the group itself!

Thanks!!

Comment: I just figured out that this is TRUE! I found it as an exercise when I googled my question! So a proof would be needed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** If the quotient $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic then $G$ is abelian.

Comment: Oh Yeah! ;-) thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

See M.Hall, Theory of groups, 4.4. "Groups of Orders $p, p^2, pq, p^3".

Comment: Sure! thank u...